# Is there a “Cheat Sheet” for the different types of convergence?

Tags: convergence-divergence, reference-request, self-learning, weak-convergence

When studying different topics in mathematics, such as Probability and Analysis, often new types of convergence show up. For example, Probability talks about convergence in distribution, also calling it sometimes weak convergence, which also appears in Functional Analysis, but there is also weak$*$ convergence, epi-convergence ... Anyways, sometimes things get confusing.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone knows of a “Cheat Sheet” or something similar, which presents and “organizes” all this different types of convergence. When searching on Google, I mostly find things regarding convergence of series, instead of what I’m looking for.

Just to clarify. I’m looking for a reference where the many concepts of convergence (as many as possible) are defined and possibly connected, as the case with weak convergence and convergence in distribution.

Comment: I agree. Different denomination of concepts among different areas of maths can be a pain. And it gets even worse when you talk to physicists.

Comment: Googling just now I found John D. Cook's [Modes of convergence](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/) diagrams.

Comment: He is talking mostly about convergence in Measure Theory. I’m looking for something more general, connecting measure theory and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the best cheat sheet for you is the one you write yourself. I can't imagine a better way of reaching an understanding of all the different notions of convergence than to write such a sheet.

However, I will say that the one unifying concept here is that of topology. Each different type of these convergences is really convergence of sequences (or of nets) taking place in some appropriate metric space (or topological space). In probability and analysis, the spaces in question are usually normed vector spaces (or other non-normed topological vector spaces). So if you want to look for a unifying book on the topic, I would look for a book on topological vector spaces.

Comment: I definitely agree that writing one myself will help me learn tons! The only problem is that I’m writing a dissertation, so not much time to dig into this stuff now, I’m mostly looking for an easy and quick reference, so I can understand the texts that I’m reading with less confusion. I already studied Functional Analysis and Measure Theory, so it’s more of a refresher and “knowledge organization”

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Topology book. Any suggestions on which book?

Comment: Beware: Pointwise almost everywhere convergence does not come from a topology!